# expect: launching scp after sftp

Tags: bash, sftp, expect, scp

I could really use some help. I'm still pretty new with expect. I need to launch a scp command directly after I run sftp.

I got the first portion of this script working, my main concern is the bottom portion. I really need to launch a command after this command completes. I'd rather be able to spawn another command than, hack something up like piping this with a sleep command and running it after 10 s or something weird.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
spawn sftp user@host
expect "password: "
send "123\r"
expect "$ "
sleep 2
send "cd mydir\r"
expect "$ "
sleep 2
send "get somefile\r"
expect "$ "
sleep 2
send "bye\r"
expect "$ "
sleep 2

spawn scp somefile user2@host2:/home/user2/
sleep 2
```

So i figured out I can actually get this to launch the subprocess if I use "exec" instead of spawn.. in other words:

```
exec scp somefile user2@host2:/home/user2/
```

the only problem? It prompts me for a password! This shouldn't happen, I already have the ssh-keys installed on both systems. (In other words, if I run the scp command from the host I'm running this expect script on, it will run without prompting me for a password). The system I'm trying to scp to, must be recognizing this newly spawned process as a new host, because its not picking up my ssh-key. Any ideas?

BTW, I apologize I haven't actually posted a "working" script, I can't really do that without comprimising the security of this server. I hope that doesn't detract from anyones ability to assist me.

I think the problem lies with me not terminating the initially spawned process. I don't understand expect enough to do it properly. If I try "close" or "eof", it simply kills the entire script, which I don't want to do just yet (because I still need to scp the file to the second host).

Comment: You are sending commands to sftp, then you want to execute scp command and again want to send commands to sftp?

Comment: Dinesh, I'm trying to grab a file from host-a via sftp, and place it onto host-b via scp. We are only provided access to host-a via sftp, so using scp on host-a (or any other method), is not an option.

Comment: You might consider using a (inherently scriptable) client such as lftp which can speak both protocols. No need to script two different clients.

Comment: Does host-a and host-b support pubkey? It would be much more simpler to automate and much more safe than storing passwords plaintext in a script.

Comment: I'm in the process of trying to get my keys stored on host-a. In the meantime, until that gets accomplished, I have to go with plaintext for host-a. I do have my key on host-b (and host-b's key on my system), which is why I'm confused with this behavior.

Comment: Is it truly **only** "after sftp" where this happens? You comment out the sftp parts of the same script, and the scp works? If not, you can simplify your question by removing the irrelevancies.

Comment: Charles, I will look into that. Given my time restraints that will be something I will have to wait for a weekend project.

Comment: Which "that"? Simplifying the problem, or rewriting to use lftp? (I'd argue that the rewrite would be quicker and easier than continuing down the path you're already on).

Comment: Charles, I'm not sure I follow..(in regards to the above comment)? I will take a look at ftp when I get home, hopefully I can get something whipped up.

Comment: @ slugman : Just like how added `send` and `expect` commands after spawning sftp, you have to do the same for scp also.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your SSH private key is loaded into an agent, and that the environment variables pointing to that agent are active in the session where you're calling scp.

```
[[ $SSH_AUTH_SOCK ]] || {       # if no agent already running...
  eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"        # ...then start one...
  ssh-add /path/to/your/ssh/key # ...load your key...
  started_ssh_agent=1           # and flag that we started it ourselves
}

# ...put your script here...

[[ $started_ssh_agent ]] && {   # if we started the agent ourselves...
  eval "$(ssh-agent -s -k)"     # ...then clean up nicely when done.
}
```

---

As an aside, I'd **strongly** suggest replacing the code given in the question with something like the following:

```
lftp -u user,123 -e 'get /mydir/somefile -o localfile' sftp://host </dev/null
lftp scp://user2@host2 -e 'put localfile -o /home/user2/somefile' </dev/null
```

Each connection handled in one line, and no silliness messing around with `expect`.

Comment: Charles, thats a lot simpler than what I was attempting to do. Now, I can actually use this in my master script and actually call the local variables without $::(env) stuff.. I'd like to learn tcl someday but right now is not the time. I can work with this, I'll report back with a solution.

Comment: Charles, I was to lost in expect-land to realize how simple lftp could be. Furthermore, its faster too! I modified my master script to use lftp instead of expect. This expect script was launched as a subprocess, so now I can ditch it with a single lftp line. Thanks :)

Comment: @slugman, glad to help. BTW, I wasn't quite doing things right around agent shutdown; see edits.